# Center SVG elements to its area

Tags: html, svg

Look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhcgolds/gWyhE/).

The code is complex but the question in simple. I just want to center the SVG content of the gauge chart. You can see the **red square** that is the **SVG area**. I want to content(the graphic) to fit on its center. Don't mind if it crops, I can adjust it later.

I tried with CSS `margin` and `padding` but none worked. And Kendo have no method to center it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gWyhE/1/

In the fiddle I gave you I've added `padding-bottom` and `padding-left` in the element `.gauge-container svg`.

Hope i helped.

Comment: What if JSFiddle blew up one day? Both the question and this answer become utterly useless. Please post your code in your answer with a better explanation

Comment: Nothing to explain actually, only 2 simple elements.

Comment: @Bojangles This is the reason that I don't post the entire code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053893/ie9-x-frame-options-deny-upload 60 views just 1 answer. Some people are lazy to read a long code and simply close your question without reach the middle. My question is simple and the code is too long to post it entirely.

Comment: @yotam you got it on the fiddle. But doing it on my real code doesnt worked. And they're the same. Strange...

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you but that is my question. I can't really explain about padding-bottom and/or left.. it just simple function such as margin that control the position of the item/div/element or whatever by pixels.. a 3 - 2 more lines wont change a thing, it just basic of html..

Comment: Yeah I know. The fact is that I added the red borders just on fiddle to explain better the question. My real code hasn't that borders. And is reight the border that do the trick. Thank you. I will accept your answer.

Comment: The fiddle does not center the SVG in modern browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you need to add [`margin`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/radialgauge) to your `gaugeArea`:

```
margin: { top: -margin, left: margin/2, right: -margin/2, bottom: margin/2 },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VZAa7/

Note sure why the top margin has to be double though...

Comment: Your answer resolved my problem not just for the horizontal align but the vertical too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your svg viewBox to preserve the aspect ratio in the middle:

For example:

```
<svg 
  ...
  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"
  viewBox="0 0 370 430"
  ...
></svg>
```

This means the content of the svg will scale from the middle, rather than the left or right.

More information can be found here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html

Also, to make sure everything is scaling properly, you can apply the following CSS to your svg:

```
.responsive-svg {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%; 
  height:auto;
}
```